# Don't fail Jenkins on Git Publisher errors

Tags: git, github, jenkins

When a build succeeds in Jenkins, I push to GitHub with the Git Publisher plugin.

Every once in a while, github.com times out on the push and I have this in the build log:

```
Pushing HEAD to branch develop at repo github
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true push git@github.com:REPO.git HEAD:develop
ERROR: Failed to push branch develop to github
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true push git@github.com:itext/itextpdf.git HEAD:develop" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

(Java stacktrace omitted)

Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
```

I do not want the build to be marked as a failure when pushing to github.com doesn't work.
However, I do want it to be marked as unstable.

Reason:

- Failed build: mail gets send to dev leads and QA (me), ***and*** to developer who broke the build
- Unstable build: mail gets only sent to dev leads and QA (me), *but **not** to the developer who last committed*

I don't want individual developers to be concerned with a temporary failure at GitHub, these things are usually resolved without intervention by the next time the build runs.

Other than splitting the Git Publisher step off to another build job, how can I change the build result from failed to unstable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by splitting the job in two parts: first building, and after a succesfull build, start a new job that pushes to the remote repo.